# Handle missing data in titanic dataset

Tags: pandas, feature-extraction

There is a titanic dataset. It has an 'Age' independent feature with 177 missing values. I am looking at a solution in github but can't understand one line. Can you guys explain me please.

THe line is:

```
data['Age'].dropna().sample(data['Age'].isnull().sum(), random_state=0)
```

Comment: `dropna()` removes all nan values, then `sample` a total of `data['Age'].isnull().sum()` values from those (non-null) with a given random seed.

Answer (score 1):

First it drop the null value  with `dropna`

```
data['Age'].dropna()
```

then use above output , it `sample` the not null column with the same length of not null value

```
sample(data['Age'].isnull().sum(), random_state=0)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what sample function does here

Comment: @UjjwalMahajan you can check the example here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html~